# Google Maps Api Key with already created keystore

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play

I am adding Google Maps into my application for the first time.
I have gone through several tutorials for getting the Google Maps API key for deployment.

But every where the first step indicated is to create a debug.KeyStore OR the create our own application keyStore

Then copy our SHA1 and paste it with the package name while generating API Key.

My small doubt is:
I am giving an Update of my application and added Google Maps in my version 2.

I do have the keyStore of my application that is already live on the play store.

So what do i do now as I already have my key and have to use the same key for the Update.

I dont want to mess up things at the time of deployment.

Please Help.

Comment: Yes you can use that,not need to create again .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be use that keystore file which is already within the application on Google Play Store. Because if you create new keystore file then you have to regenerate process again.

So you have to go to with your old one keystore file.

Comment: SO how do i get the SHA1 of my previous key?

Comment: you can get by using alias of your keystore file using Command prompt.

Comment: any link to guide me do that... I am very new to these terminologies

Comment: Yes i got a source for that..Thankz alot; your answer helped!

Comment: Ur wel come.. Glad to help you!!

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the keystore that you already have. Basically you have no other option.

Comment: So how do i get the SHA1 of my previous key?